# How to read Ajax class response send from a ASP.NET MVC Contoller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello and many thanks for you help! I'm new to Web Programming.

I have an Ajax call to a controller in ASP .NET MVC.
When response received I try to get multiple information from the response and use it on my HTML.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Function", "Controller")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Parameter: $(this).attr("id") }), 
    type: "POST",             
    contentType: "application/json",
    timeout: 10000,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        var result = result.d;
        $("#textbox1").attr("value", result.attr1);
        $("#textbox2").attr("value", result.attr2);
        $("#textbox3").attr("value", result.attr3);
    }
```

The Controller:

```
    public class response
    {
        public string attr1;
        public string attr2;
        public string attr3;
    }

    [HttpPost]  
    public response Function(String Parameter)
    {
        response returnVal = new response();
        returnVal.attr1 = "Dummy1";
        returnVal.attr2 = "Dummy2";
        returnVal.attr3 = "Dummy3";
        return returnVal;
    }
```

In the controller I receive the information but when the response should be parrsed nothing happen.
I guess an error occurs or I parse the data badly.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Remove this line in your javascript: var result = result.d;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
public JsonResult Function(String Parameter)
    {
        response returnVal = new response();
        returnVal.attr1 = "Dummy1";
        returnVal.attr2 = "Dummy2";
        returnVal.attr3 = "Dummy3";
        return Json(returnVal);
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is working! Thanks both im1dermike and artm !

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your return type for the controller method to `ActionResult` (I have no idea what `response` is).  Then change your return line to this:

```
return Json(returnVal, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: response is my cutom class created just locally (used it for an example) - In the end I'll make a proper model class